# increasing number of nodes, but heap comparison shows no detached dom, and dom size is stable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-leaks, profiling, google-chrome-devtools

I am exploring a memory leak on a angular js app. I am using chrome devtools timeline and heap snapshot comparison. I execute a simple scenario with the following actions:
 1. add a new row
 2. remove the new row

The timeline show an increase of the number of nodes. action (1) adds 89 nodes. action (2) do not remove those as it should expected.

When profiling the same scenario with a comparison of 2 heap snapshots, no detached dom is to be found.

The "normal" dom size remains stable. I checked it using $('*').length.

Where can I hunt these additional dom nodes shown by the timeline ?
Or is it maybe that one of the devtools feature is lying?

thanks for any hint.

edit: could it be that this dom nodes are actually contained in some js vars, and therefore counted by the timeline, but not recorded as such by the heap snapshot comparison ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this has a simple answer. By using the "containment" option of the view dropdown that has as default value "Summary", at the top of the devtool window.